# How can I pass a file list to a bootbox callback?

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootbox

When my user try to upload several files, I trigger a bootbox modal to make him decide on 2 possible options. On the bootbox callback, I want to iterate over a list of file that I get from my file input. The problem is that my file list variable is empty in the callback.

Have a look at the code:

```
this.loadFiles = function(files){
    if (files.length>1){ //here, 'files' is populated
        bootbox.dialog({
          message: APi18n.__("media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_message"),
          title: TAPi18n.__("media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_header"),
          animate: true,
          buttons: {
                danger: {
                    label: TAPi18n.__('cancel'),
                    className: "btn-default",
                        },
                success: {
                    label: TAPi18n.__('media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_ok_button'),
                    className: "btn-info",
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log(files); //here, 'files' is empty
                        _.each(files, function(file){
                       //etc.
```

How can I access to my `files` list in my bootbox callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May your `files` variable be altered "later on" in the scope of your `loadFiles` function? If so, you should move the alteration part *after* using it for your dialog:

```
this.loadFiles = function(files){
    if (files.length>1){ //here, 'files' is populated
        bootbox.dialog({
          message: APi18n.__("media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_message"),
          title: TAPi18n.__("media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_header"),
          animate: true,
          buttons: {
                danger: {
                    label: TAPi18n.__('cancel'),
                    className: "btn-default",
                        },
                success: {
                    label: TAPi18n.__('media_warning_multiple_file_input_modal_ok_button'),
                    className: "btn-info",
                    callback: function() {
                        _.each(currFiles, function(file){
                       //etc.
                       });
                       // <--- HERE
                    }
```

Comment: Yeah I was not sure if `var currFiles = files` would effectively duplicate the array... seems like it doesn't. Sorry, I will update my answer.

Comment: Updated. Is that pretty much it?